# PCB from circuit diagram

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, schematics

Can anyone please explain why this U1A and U1B is there and how can it be converted into a schematic in Easy EDA?

[image: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/610mQaFartL.SX522.jpg]

(Source: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/610mQaFartL._SX522_.jpg )

Comment: U1A and U1B mean that these two components are sitting in the same physical package (which will be U1 on the PCB). In the EDA software there should be a model of that U1 which is including multiple components inside.

Comment: Please add the source for the picture / schematic.

Comment: can someone also tell the software on which this pcb is made

Comment: @fghbnhj - Hi, thanks for mentioning the website which you said was the source of that image you copied. However that is not enough. We need you to add the actual URL for the webpage / PDF / video etc. which was the source page from which you copied that schematic. Please [edit] the question to add that specific URL. Thanks.

Comment: @fghbnhj - You said: "*can someone also tell the software on which this pcb is made*" Unfortunately that doesn't make sense - you said "this pcb" but no PCB is shown in your question, so I guess you mean something else. Are you asking what EDA software could be used to create a PCB layout (PCB design) from that schematic? Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail what you are trying to do - what is your overall task / project - and explain *specifically* where you are stuck and what you have already tried, to solve your own problem (whatever that is). Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I meant that on which software is this schematic made on. Thankyou for your correction

Comment: The schematic could have been drawn in any ECAD schematic program - Altium, Orcad, KiCAD, or ...

Comment: @fghbnhj - Thanks for adding a source link. However that just goes to the image, not to the webpage (with more details). To try to help you, I did some searching. Is [this](https://www.amazon.in/MYPCB-Treble-Board-Active-NE5532/dp/B0C6FFGH1P) the Amazon product page from which you copied the schematic? If so, we can add that as the source URL. Thanks.

Comment: I correctly guessed the very high prices numbers were Rupees in India but I have never seen the Rupee symbol before.

Answer (score 1):

The `R##`, `D##`, `C##`, etc. are known as [Reference Designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator). `U##` is the common designator for an IC such as in your case an Op Amp. Manufacturers of these components, whether it be an Op Amp, Digital IC, etc., pack multiple of these devices into a physical package (chip/IC). Usually 2, 4, 6, or 8 devices per package. In your case, you have a dual op-amp, meaning in one package there are 2 op amps. In schematics, we typically differentiate the two (or more) devices by appending A, B, C... to the end of the reference designator to indicate which device we are using within the chip.

If you are using EasyEDA, I can't provide information on how to import multi-device ICs, but the reference designator does not matter in the end result if you are using individual single op amps.

I would suggest using a more user-friendly EDA such as [KiCad](https://www.kicad.org/).